# Remove shopware6 synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-removal-request

I wonder why [shopware6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopware6) is a synonym for [shopware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopware). I think it would make a lot of sense to separate them especially because we have the [shopware5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopware5) tag which is independent.

I think it makes sense to have all three separate tags since questions tagged [shopware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopware) should be version independent whereas [shopware5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopware5) and [shopware6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopware6) can be used to distinguish between the two versions. This distinction is necessary from my point of view because shopware 6 has a different underlying architecture (symfony/twig). So it does need some sort of distinction and a tag is the easiest. For php for example we have different version tags as well.

Answer (score 8):

I read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407483/288568 and the opinion there is  tags are there "to filter by expertise". A Shopware 6 developer might have very small expertise in Shopware 5 (and vice versa), as lots of things changed between version 5 and 6 and it's more like a rewrite on a different tech stack.

So I agree with removing the synonym.

Answer (score 7):

I fully agree. Shopware 6 is completely different to Shopware 5. Please separate.